# Ajax calls doubles every time I click a link to open a window in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table with action column and column has button(link) to show details of that row.

Following is the code that shows the button in every row `:rowid` will be actual ineger number.

```
<a data-path="http://example/rowdetails/:rowid" class="btn btn-info btn-xs load-ajax-modal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dynamic-modal">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show Details">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Following is the html for dynamic modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="dynamic-modal" class="modal modal-wide hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Row Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--Dynamic body content appears here-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.Modal -->
```

Following is the Javascript that I am using.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    // when .modal-wide opened, set content-body height based on browser height; 200 is appx height of modal padding, modal title and button bar
    $(".modal-wide").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
        var height = $(window).height() - 200;
        $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
    });

    /*Dynamic Modal window to load row details usin ajax load*/
    $('.load-ajax-modal').on('click',function () {
        url = $(this).data('path');
        //ajax call using load function
        $('.modal-body').load(url, function (result) {
            $('#dynamic-modal').removeClass('hide');
        });
    });
});
```

**Problem**
Everything works good here when I click the button in a row, `one` single ajax(xhr) call is made. second time I click this time for the same url there are `two` ajax requests. third time I click a button there are `four`, fourth time `eight` and so on, it doubles every-time the previous number.

I saw in other posts and tried .one() .live() .die() etc but I think I could figure out where exactly use these functions (I tried these functions with $('.load-ajax-modal') and it doesn't seems to work).

Thanks,

K

Comment: try `return false;` from the handler. if that doesn't work, try using another event to load the contents of that url. the click is finicky because bootstrap also uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ajaxComplete handler fires everytime any Ajax request completes and each time it adds a new function as a handler when the button is clicked. So, not so surprising that the handler function gets executed once, then twice, then four times ...

What you should do is use event delegation.

```
$(function onDocumentReady() {
    var $modal = $('#dynamic-modal');
    var $modalBody = $('.modal-body');
    var $window = $(window);

    $modal.on("show.bs.modal", function () {
        var height = $window.height() - 200;
        $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.load-ajax-modal', function (e) {
        url = $(this).data('path');
        //ajax call using load function
        $modalBody.load(url, function (result) {
            $modal.modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

Couple of points to remember:

1. Always cache the jQuery object ( e.g. $(window) ) in a variable if you use it multiple times. This makes sure that jQuery does not need to query the DOM everytime you look for a specific DOM element.
2. Read up on [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) . It makes sure that your event handler gets executed even when the elements are added dynamically to your page. Similar to what jQuery.live() offered but that has long been deprecated.

Comment: Should I place this in `$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {`

Comment: Check the edited code. You do not need an ajaxComplete callback at all.

Comment: Also, you do not need 'hide' class in your modal HTML. Just use what Bootstrap provides. When you call $modal.modal('show'), bootstrap adds the class 'in' to the modal which shows it. This also makes sure your height manipulating script gets executed when the modal is shown.

Comment: Great, it worked. one confusion how is `$(document).on('click', '.load-ajax-modal', function (e) {` different from `$('.load-ajax-modal').on('click',function () {`

Comment: The former says whenever a ".load-ajax-modal" element is clicked, even if such an element will be added in the future and is therefore not present on the page right now, execute this function. The latter says, whenever a ".load-ajax-modal" element that is present on the page right now is clicked, execute this function. I have linked to a page describing event delegation on the answer, I suggest you read up on that and understand the underlying concept.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, one more question. if there is ajax loading and I fire another ajax by quickly clicking the button it kind of get stuck. how can I handle multiple requests fired together.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are appending clicks to already existing element. Quickest fix will be to off all registered actions before attaching new one: `$('.load-ajax-modal').off('click').on('click',function () {...` Like I said that's is just a workaround, to get rid of that problem dispose dom elements when the dialog is closed.

Comment: Great, this worked. But why do you say this is workaround, what would be the right way to do it?

Comment: When you are opening modal window you are creating some DOM elements. Just simply destroy them on modal close.